footmisc, left-aligned marks flushed to left margin, first line indented with subsequent lines flushed left
How can I achieve a footnote layout like the below with footmisc? I'd like left-aligned marks that are flushed left (ie to the left margin), and for the text, an indent from the left margin of some fixed amount while new lines are also flushed left to the margin. I faked the footnotes in the image with some hboxes in the document body.

The hang option to footmisc almost does it, except the entire footnote text is indented, see below. I also thought of trying to set \footnotemargin to some negative value or zero and then set \footnotelayout to have the first-line indent, but you can set \footnotemargin to -20em if you want and still the text is just next to the right of the mark. I also spent time fiddling with flushmargin, marginal, and setting various lengths provided by footmisc but couldn't make it work.

MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bottom,hang]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[7]%
\footnote{one}\footnote{two}\footnote{thr}%
\footnote{fou}\footnote{fiv}\footnote{six}%
\footnote{sev}\footnote{eig}%
\footnote{Foobar}%
\footnote{\lipsum[7]}
\end{document}


There is imho currently no user interface. You would have to patch the command
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum,etoolbox}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@makefntext{\hss\@makefnmark}{\@makefnmark\hss}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[7]%
\footnote{one}\footnote{two}\footnote{thr}%
\footnote{fou}\footnote{fiv}\footnote{six}%
\footnote{sev}\footnote{eig}%
\footnote{Foobar}%
\footnote{\lipsum[7]}
\end{document}



One option would be to use some of the built-in commands provided by the memoir class to achieve the result, without footmisc.
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage[bottom,hang]{footmisc}

\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0pt}
\setlength{\footparindent}{1.8em}
\footmarkstyle{\hbox to \footparindent{\textsuperscript{#1}\hfill}}

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{% to send footnotes to the bottom
    \vfil
    \kern -3pt%
    \hrule width 0.4\columnwidth
    \kern 2.6pt}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[7]%
\footnote{one}\footnote{two}\footnote{thr}%
\footnote{fou}\footnote{fiv}\footnote{six}%
\footnote{sev}\footnote{eig}%
\footnote{Foobar}%
\footnote{\lipsum[7]}
\end{document}


